# Where can i find Mule Object Store Schema?

Tags: schema, mule

So far i was able to create an example using ObjectStore from mule but it doesnt compile with an error saying Failed to read schema document...

My header is like folow:

```
<mule xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:servlet="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet"
xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jdbc"
xmlns:ssl="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/servlet/current/mule-servlet.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/current/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.4/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.4/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssl/current/mule-ssl.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd"
version="3.4.0">
```

Where can I find the schema since it is not where it was suppose to be?

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd"
```

mule version 3.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The schema location you are using is correct: `http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd`

So you're not missing a schema but the module itself. You need to install it in your application. For this follow this guide: http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/guide/install.html

Comment: It is installed, but the error i get accessing that url is "The Page Cannot be Found" if you go to http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ you will see there is no objectstore folder to access...

Comment: There is absolutely no need for the schema to actually be served at that URL: the XML validator redirects it to a schema embedded in the module JAR.

Comment: Well idk what was the problem, ive configured with maven, and it doesnt work, then i just sent it to run without maven and it worked Oo, anyway, ty David :)

Answer (score 2):

The link to the documentation from above is no longer valid. To install the object store I had to add the dependency to the pom and the schema from the above answer.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-objectstore</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

`http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstorehttp://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd`